# How do I evaluate this integral: $ \int \frac{x^2+3x-2}{x^5+x^4+x^3-x^2-x-1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

How do I evaluate this integral: $ \int \frac{x^2+3x-2}{x^5+x^4+x^3-x^2-x-1}dx$

I already got it into this form $-\frac{2}{9}\int \frac{x}{x^2+x+1}dx-\frac{4}{9}\int\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}dx +\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{x}{(x^2+x+1)^2}dx+\frac{8}{3}\int\frac{1}{(x^2+x+1)^2}dx+\frac{2}{9}\int\frac{1}{x-1}dx$

(partical fraction decomposition)

But I cannot proceed :/

How can I deal with all the annoying quotients?

Comment: Search up rational function integration. The idea is to complete the square on the denominator (in most cases). One I found is https://www.math24.net/integration-rational-functions/#:~:text=Integration%20of%20Rational%20Functions,x)Q(x).&text=To%20integrate%20a%20proper%20rational,of%20integrals%20of%20simpler%20functions. Also, where did you find this nasty problem? Doesn't feel like a textbook problem.

Comment: You can find the integral of $\frac{x}{x^2+x+1}$ by writing it as $\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x+1} - \frac{1}{2(x^2+x+1)}$. The first part can be found using a $u$-sub, and the other part you can find by completing the square.

Comment: Try completing the square so you can solve it with $\arctan$, if there is a multiplication like $(x^2+x+1)^2$ do partial fraction decomposition again

Comment: how am I supposed to use partial fraction again on $1/(x^2+x+1)^2$

Comment: Your tipps dont want to work for me :/

Comment: okey my only struggle left is $\frac{x}{x^2+x+1}$ and $\frac{x}{(x^2+x+1)^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Use $\left(  \frac{5x+4}{x^2+x+1}\right)’ =- \frac5{x^2+x+1} -\frac{3(x-2)}{(x^2+x+1)^2}$ to integrate in compact form below

\begin{align}
& \int \frac{x^2+3x-2}{x^5+x^4+x^3-x^2-x-1}dx
= \int \frac{x-2}{(x^2+x+1)^2}dx\\
= & -\frac13 \frac{5x+4}{x^2+x+1}- \frac53 \int \frac{1}{x^2+x+1}dx\\
 = & -\frac13 \frac{5x+4}{x^2+x+1}- \frac{10}{3\sqrt3} \tan^{-1}\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt3}+C
\end{align}